# How do I perform operations on a Pandas Dataframe with duplicate Datetimes?

Tags: pandas, indexing

For example, given a Dataframe `df1`:

```
Date         Computers Syms
2011-01-10    400.     1
2011-01-10    500.     1
2012-04-12    450.     1
```

and variables `log = some_df.loc[some_df.index, 'Cat']`
 and `price = df2.loc[:, log]`, 
I want to calculate

```
df1.loc[df1.index, syms] = price * log
```

where `syms` is just the Series. When I try the above command, I get the error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

How should I set the column values of `syms` to that expression given that some indices are equivalent?

An expected output would be

```
Date         syms1            syms2
2011-01-10    price * log       price * log
2011-01-10    price * log       price * log
2012-04-12    price * log       price * log
```

Comment: It is unclear to me ...

Comment: What do you need clarification on?

Comment: Expected out put and your df1 looks like a pd.Series

Comment: I completely changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `loc`, you can use `:` to indicate all of that axis, either index or columns.

```
df_trades.loc[:, 'syms'] = houses * cars

df_trades

         Date  Computers   syms
0  2011-01-10        400  80000
1  2011-01-10        500  80000
2  2012-04-12        450  80000
```

---

You can also use `pd.DataFrame.assign` to produce a copy with the new column

```
df_trades.assign(syms=houses * cars)

         Date  Computers   syms
0  2011-01-10        400  80000
1  2011-01-10        500  80000
2  2012-04-12        450  80000
```

---

If `syms` is a series of column names

```
syms = pd.Series(['syms1', 'syms2'])

df_trades.assign(**dict((s, houses * cars) for s in syms))

         Date  Computers  syms1  syms2
0  2011-01-10        400  80000  80000
1  2011-01-10        500  80000  80000
2  2012-04-12        450  80000  80000
```

Comment: whole night only you and me :-) LOL

Comment: We'll see... even so, we got this!

Comment: So syms isn't one column. It's a series of columns.

Comment: That series is a column in df1

Comment: prices and shares are also series :O

Comment: @dirtysocks45 answer updated.  Also, it is frowned upon to change the nature of your question.  It renders answers irrelevant and isn't fair to those who made an effort to answer.  It has never in the history of SO been frowned upon to ask another question that is different than the first question you asked.

Comment: Where are prices and shares in your original question?

Comment: @dirtysocks45 make sure you know what you want to know  in the next question

Comment: @dirtysocks45 also, just to provide more context and insight.  One of the things we want... are upvotes and accepted answers.  By asking a new question, that gives us another opportunity to provide an answer and garner votes.  Just sayin'

Comment: @piRSquared Could you check my latest question on applying vectorized operations on datframes? I think this time I finally worded it really well.

Answer (score 1):

```
df ['Syms'] = 400 * 200 
df
Out[189]: 
         Date  Computers   syms
0  2011-01-10        400  80000
1  2011-01-10        500  80000
2  2012-04-12        450  80000
```

---

Edit

```
syms=['sys1','sys2']
d = dict.fromkeys(syms, 200*400)
df.assign(**d)
```

Comment: I completely changed my question

Comment: @dirtysocks45 should it be a new question ?

Comment: I don't want to clog the feed.

Comment: I'll be honest... I've never seen the feed get clogged

Comment: @dirtysocks45 if the log and price still a value it would not change the answer